# is it legal to give a null handle to renderpass begin

Tags: vulkan

Wanted to make a little voxelization pass, I wanted to know if it is legal to give a null framebuffer to a render pass (with 0 attachments) because I do not need to write on a framebuffer.

I ask this question because in the specs in the renderpassbegin, it is explicitly write :

> `framebuffer` must be a valid `VkFramebuffer` handle.
>
> Both of `framebuffer`, and `renderPass` must have been created, allocated, or retrieved from the same `VkDevice`.

Comment: "*voxelization pass*" Wouldn't it be easier to use a Compute Shader?

Comment: Not really because I need the rasterization (Cyril Crassin 's article) (Voxel Cone tracing)

Answer (score 2):

NULL is not a valid handle. So yes, you will need an (empty) `VkFramebuffer`, even if the render pass has no attachments. Even an empty framebuffer defines concepts like the width/height of the rendering area, which must remain fixed throughout the render pass. By contrast, viewport state is either baked into the pipeline or dynamically specified.

Comment: This is correct. The reason it's necessary even with no attachments is that the rasterizer needs to know the dimensions of the area its rasterizing to. It could almost get this info from the viewport(s), but e.g. for tiling architectures they need memory per tile, and deriving that from viewports would be complicated and require unexpected memory allocations while executing command buffers.